# Sparql operation on union of two queries

Tags: sparql, union

I have two sparql querys ,  simplifying my problem :

query 1:

```
 select ?letter ?number
```

-> results ({a1}{b2}{d4})

....
query 2:

```
 select ?anotherletter ?anotherNumber
```

-> results ({b2}{c3})

How can i join the 2 querys to obtain the sum of the second column, maybe same values of a one lista couldnt be in the second.
The result of the query has to be

```
{a,1}{b,4}{c,3}{d,4}
```

Is there a propper way to do that?

Comment: `select ?letter (sum(?number) as ?cnt) {  {QUERY1} UNION {QUERY2} } group by ?letter` - and yes, the variables should be the same in both UNION parts.

Comment: sure thats what i need ,  answer the question with that Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that gives @UninformedUser worked:

```
select ?letter (sum(?number) as ?cnt) {  {QUERY1} UNION {QUERY2} } group by ?letter
```

and yes, the variables should be the same in both UNION parts. –
UninformedUser